# RESTful uploading of a video file in PHP

Tags: rest, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to upload a video file to a server using POST request. There is not much information available about it in the internet.

I usually do check the data what i have send using this code

```
$params = $_REQUEST;
return $params;
```

I check it in POSTMAN. I have table called video_review

id
video_url
movie_id
user_id
date_time

when i choose a video file and click send i want the location of video file to be saved into the video_url field. But in the controller when i run this code `return $params;` i get nothing.

**EDIT**

Made some progress

```
public function actionCreate_video_review()
    {

        $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma","mkv");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['video_url']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


if (  ($_FILES["video_url"]["type"] == "video/mp4")|| ($_FILES["video_url"]["type"] == "video/x-matroska")

&& ($_FILES["video_url"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts) )

  {
  if ($_FILES["video_url"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    return   $_FILES["video_url"]["error"];
    }
  else
    {

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["video_url"]["name"]))
            {
                echo $_FILES["video_url"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
            else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["video_url"]["tmp_name"],
                "upload/" . $_FILES["video_url"]["name"]);
                echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["video_url"]["name"];
                return $_FILES["video_url"]["name"];
            }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it working.

```
 //POST Video Reviews
    public function actionCreate_video_review()
    {

        $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma","mkv");
        $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['video_url']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if (  ($_FILES["video_url"]["type"] == "video/mp4")|| ($_FILES["video_url"]["type"] == "video/x-matroska")&& ($_FILES["video_url"]["size"] < 90000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts) )
        {
            if ($_FILES["video_url"]["error"] > 0)
            {
                return   $_FILES["video_url"]["error"];
            }
            else
            {

                if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["video_url"]["name"]))
                {
                    echo $_FILES["video_url"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                }
                else
                {
                    $model = new \app\models\VideoReview();
                    $model->video_url = $_FILES["video_url"]["name"];
                    $model->save();
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["video_url"]["tmp_name"],
                        \Yii::$app->basePath. '/web/uploads/' . $_FILES["video_url"]["name"]);

                        return $_FILES["video_url"]["name"];
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return   $_FILES["video_url"]["error"] ."Error";   
            }
}
```

Comment: Check out FileValidator. It can make almost all the checks against types and mime-types.

Comment: thanks i will do that @SilverFire Does that mean the way i got it working is wrong???

Comment: May I add, that `UploadedFile` is also useful in this case http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html, as it already contains all the information about the uploaded file that you are getting